# In Tezos-Reward-Distributor, I'm getting this response when I dry run the payment

Tags: baking, tezos-reward-distributor, rewards

I run this command:

```
python3 src/main.py -C 53 -M 3 -D payment_alias
```

and get this as an error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "/home/tezos-reward-distributor/src/pay/payment_consumer.py", line 70, in run
      payment_logs = batch_payer.pay(payment_items, self.verbose, dry_run=self.dry_run)
    File "/home/tezos-reward-distributor/src/pay/batch_payer.py", line 79, in pay
      payments_log = self.pay_single_batch_wrap(payment_items_chunk, verbose=verbose, dry_run=dry_run)
    File "/home/tezos-reward-distributor/src/pay/batch_payer.py", line 94, in pay_single_batch_wrap
      return_code, operation_hash = self.pay_single_batch(payment_items, verbose, dry_run=dry_run)
    File "/home/tezos-reward-distributor/src/pay/batch_payer.py", line 175, in pay_single_batch
      bytes = parse_json_response(forge_command_response, verbose=verbose)
    File "/home/tezos-reward-distributor/src/util/rpc_utils.py", line 16, in parse_json_response
      raise Exception("Unknown client response format")
    Exception: Unknown client response format
```

The creator of the distributor was speaking with someone having this exact issue (see [here](https://github.com/habanoz/tezos-reward-distributor/issues/38#issuecomment-462019424) and [here](https://github.com/habanoz/tezos-reward-distributor/issues/38#issuecomment-462023712)).

I don't quite understand how Issie81 fixed his problem. Could someone please give me further indications?

Comment: Please provide the exact command you are running in your post so people can try to reproduce your problem, thanks

Comment: issie81 is trying to run TRD using a KT1 address for "payment_alias" which TRD does not support at the time of this posting. Have you migrated to v3 of TRD? It has many improvements.

Comment: I had a similar issue on v3. Pulling the newest code from github solved this issue for me.